# which webhook events specifically are fired when a subscription is set to "unpaid"

Tags: webhooks

which webhook events specifically are fired when a subscription is set to "unpaid"

take advantage of one of the settings in the dashboard you linked to in order to "set subscription to 'unpaid' if a recurring payment hasn't been collected within 15 days". This should trigger a webhook for `subscription.updated` or something similar